# How to run NSTimer in background for 1 or 2 days with time interval around 300 secs in iOS?

Tags: ios, timer, location

I am working on a project in which i need to get location updates in all states of application at a particular time interval. I have used NSTimer to call locationUpdate method at a particular time interval in background and foreground. But Timer is only works in background for 1-2 hours if interval time is around 30 secs, When i increase interval to 300 secs timer does not work in background even for 10 mins. Please tell me - Is there any way to run timer in background for at least one day with time interval around 300 secs or get location update at particular time interval in all states????

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you prefer NSTimer over background location updates?

```
// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
 // Add the new locations to the hike
[self.hike addLocations:locations];

// Defer updates until the user hikes a certain distance
// or when a certain amount of time has passed.
if (!self.deferringUpdates) {
  CLLocationDistance distance = self.hike.goal - self.hike.distance;
  NSTimeInterval time = [self.nextAudible timeIntervalSinceNow];
  [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance
                                                     timeout:time];
self.deferringUpdates = YES;
   }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: I am unable to reach to the  solution. Can you please elaborate a little bit? What are nextAudible, deferringUpdates here?? @eltomato

Comment: This code is described in the link I provided below the code! I think background locations is exactly what you need!

Comment: I have used this method but location update is not defering !!!! @eltomato